# How do you query for something in SQL and exclude the results from a sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, latitude-longitude

I currently have two queries that were handed to me. The first searches for contacts in our system within a 50 mile radius of some address. The second query does the same thing except it searches a 100 mile radius.

What I need to do is modify the second query so that it excludes the results from the first query. If you can visualize it we're basically creating a doughnut shaped area that is 50 miles thick.

Here is the first query (50 mile radius of LA):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t0.name ASC, t0.accountid) AS RowNumber, t0.accountid as pkt0
, t0.name as cn
, t0.name as c1
, t1.name as c2
, t1.homephone as c3
, t1.mobilephone as c4
, t1.officephone as c5
, t1.contactid as pkt1

FROM [account] as t0
Left Join [contact] as t1
ON t0.primarycontactid = t1.contactid

WHERE (((
((t0.shippingaddress not like '') AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude >= 33.6907920399124 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude <= 34.4136759600876 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude >= -118.679928573928 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude <= -117.807441426072 ))
)) AND (t0.deleted = 0))
) _tmpInlineView
WHERE RowNumber > 0
```

Here is the second query (100 mile radius of LA):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t0.name ASC, t0.accountid) AS RowNumber, t0.accountid as pkt0
, t0.name as cn
, t0.name as c1
, t1.name as c2
, t1.homephone as c3
, t1.mobilephone as c4
, t1.officephone as c5
, t1.contactid as pkt1

FROM [account] as t0
Left Join [contact] as t1
ON t0.primarycontactid = t1.contactid

WHERE (((
((t0.shippingaddress not like '') AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude >= 33.3293500798248 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude <= 34.7751179201752 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude >= -119.11615629035 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude <= -117.37121370965 ))
)) AND (t0.deleted = 0))
) _tmpInlineView
WHERE RowNumber > 0
```

The second query is correct except it must exclude the results of the first. I'm sure it's probably simple, but I haven't manually written any SQL in years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more about substracting surfaces given latitude and longitude. 

**EDIT: It's not just subtraction as there are two parts "outside" - logic broken in 100 miles logic with AND NOT ( clause for 50 miles )** 
Try with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t0.name ASC, t0.accountid) AS RowNumber, t0.accountid as pkt0
, t0.name as cn
, t0.name as c1
, t1.name as c2
, t1.homephone as c3
, t1.mobilephone as c4
, t1.officephone as c5
, t1.contactid as pkt1

FROM [account] as t0
Left Join [contact] as t1
ON t0.primarycontactid = t1.contactid

WHERE 
/* 100 miles */
(t0.shippingaddresslatitude >= 33.3293500798248 AND t0.shippingaddresslatitude <= 34.7751179201752 ) 
/* but not 50 miles */
and not( t0.shippingaddresslatitude >= 33.6907920399124 AND t0.shippingaddresslatitude <= 34.4136759600876 )
/* SAME for LONGITUDE */
AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude >= -119.11615629035 AND t0.shippingaddresslongitude <= -117.37121370965 )
and not (t0.shippingaddresslongitude >= -118.679928573928 AND t0.shippingaddresslongitude <= -117.807441426072 )


AND (t0.deleted = 0))
) _tmpInlineView
WHERE RowNumber > 0
```

Comment: I do like the idea of tackling the problem with the areas instead of getting the results and then filtering some out. However, this query returns no results for me, though it throws no errors. I'm trying to figure out why that is, but if you have any ideas let me know.

Comment: Tried to refine query, edited to fix bug and have cleaner logic

Comment: Not only does this query work, but I believe it was the proper way to write it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As long as they have the same number of parameters, use EXCEPT.

```
Select column from table1
  Except 
    Select column from table2
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t0.name ASC, t0.accountid) AS RowNumber, t0.accountid as pkt0
, t0.name as cn
, t0.name as c1
, t1.name as c2
, t1.homephone as c3
, t1.mobilephone as c4
, t1.officephone as c5
, t1.contactid as pkt1

FROM [account] as t0
Left Join [contact] as t1
ON t0.primarycontactid = t1.contactid

WHERE (((
((t0.shippingaddress not like '') AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude >= 33.3293500798248 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude <= 34.7751179201752 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude >= -119.11615629035 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude <= -117.37121370965 ))
)) AND (t0.deleted = 0))
) _tmpInlineView
WHERE RowNumber > 0
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t0.name ASC, t0.accountid) AS RowNumber, t0.accountid as pkt0
, t0.name as cn
, t0.name as c1
, t1.name as c2
, t1.homephone as c3
, t1.mobilephone as c4
, t1.officephone as c5
, t1.contactid as pkt1

FROM [account] as t0
Left Join [contact] as t1
ON t0.primarycontactid = t1.contactid

WHERE (((
((t0.shippingaddress not like '') AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude >= 33.6907920399124 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude <= 34.4136759600876 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude >= -118.679928573928 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude <= -117.807441426072 ))
)) AND (t0.deleted = 0))
) _tmpInlineView
WHERE RowNumber > 0
```

Comment: For some reason this query returns 425 rows. That is the same amount of rows the 100 mile radius query returns before I modify it with EXCEPT. The 50 mile radius query returns 271 rows so if those are being excluded from the 100 mile results then I should see 154 rows, but I see 425 still for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use except.  You  may  need to modify this depending on the flavor.  Something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t0.name ASC, t0.accountid) AS RowNumber,         t0.accountid as pkt0
, t0.name as cn
, t0.name as c1
, t1.name as c2
, t1.homephone as c3
, t1.mobilephone as c4
, t1.officephone as c5
, t1.contactid as pkt1

FROM [account] as t0
Left Join [contact] as t1
ON t0.primarycontactid = t1.contactid

WHERE (((
((t0.shippingaddress not like '') AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude >= 33.6907920399124 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude <= 34.4136759600876 ) AND     (t0.shippingaddresslongitude >= -118.679928573928 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude <= -    117.807441426072 ))
)) AND (t0.deleted = 0))
) _tmpInlineView
WHERE RowNumber > 0



EXCEPT


SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t0.name ASC, t0.accountid) AS RowNumber, t0.accountid as pkt0
, t0.name as cn
, t0.name as c1
, t1.name as c2
, t1.homephone as c3
, t1.mobilephone as c4
, t1.officephone as c5
, t1.contactid as pkt1

FROM [account] as t0
Left Join [contact] as t1
ON t0.primarycontactid = t1.contactid

WHERE (((
((t0.shippingaddress not like '') AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude >= 33.3293500798248 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslatitude <= 34.7751179201752 ) AND     (t0.shippingaddresslongitude >= -119.11615629035 ) AND (t0.shippingaddresslongitude <= -    117.37121370965 ))
)) AND (t0.deleted = 0))
) _tmpInlineView
WHERE RowNumber > 0
```

Comment: For some reason this query returns 425 rows. That is the same amount of rows the 100 mile radius query returns before I modify it with EXCEPT. The 50 mile radius query returns 271 rows so if those are being excluded from the 100 mile results then I should see 154 rows, but I see 425 still for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: The query which is returning rows with 50 mile of radius should come below the Except and the query with 100 mile of radius should come above the Except clause. Please make sure that you are doing the same.

Comment: Indeed. I even copied your query directly. The 100 is first and 50 is the latter.